# Can a doctor send you to collections for a bill they only emailed you?

Tags: medical-bill

So how about when a doctor's office sends you a bill via email that goes into your spam that you never see, but never snail mails you a bill?

I only found it because I was looking for something completely different. Shouldn't they have to send you a certified letter or something?

They are threatening to send me to collections and have added $100.00 in late fees to a bill I didn't even know about.

Comment: It's your responsibility to pay for services rendered.

Comment: Laws vary by jurisdiction, which country are you in?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You owe the money and you failed to pay. It was your email system that sent the bill to the spam folder, not the doctor's office. Your responsibility, not theirs. There's no obligation to send the bill via regular mail, though many jurisdictions require proof of delivery (such as a letter sent via certified mail) before suing you for the unpaid bill.

You may be able to negotiate away the late fee if you agree to immediately pay the full amount owing.